# input field (text field) css styling for mobile

Tags: css

In my login page, I have used `@media only screen and (orientation: portrait)` to detect mobile view. I don't want to show the cross-signed area (class="sidebar"). This works fine when I first load the page like ***picture 2***. But when I try to enter something in the text fields everything is messed up like ***picture 1*** (element in sidebar class shows up though I have used `display: none`. All I want is to show only login page (class="container"). My CSS demo is given below...

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait){
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**How can I do this ?**

[image: unexpected page]

[image: expected page]

Comment: Can you also paste your HTML snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Try not do with `@media only screen and (orientation: portrait)` try `@media only screen and (max-width:480px)` and see if works